# Best way to update user stories in multiple boards

Tags: user-stories, azure-boards

I have recently joined as a Development Team lead in an organisation and there are multiple dev teams in here each working  of their own Azure Devops board. Our teams follow a 2 weeks sprint cycle. The start date and end date for the sprint cycle in same across all teams.

The problem that we face is that at the end of the sprint, some of the developers do have unfinished user stories or tasks which need to be moved across to the new sprint. Is there anyway that we can automate this to automatically change the iteration path of unfinished user stories to the new sprint. Very often we have people who forget to that, and all our reporting goes wrong.

Comment: As your question stands, it seems to be more related to the tool in use (Azure DevOps) than to the practice itself. Other tools work differently (Jira for instance allows you to choose to automatically move items to next Sprint or backlog). With that in mind, this may end up into a tool recommendation question which is off-topic for PM.SE. I'd suggest you instead to invest the energy (and this post, potentially) to focus on why items are rolling over sprints.

Comment: Fully understand why you would want to automate this, but I think doing so might obscure data that you want. Why are these unfinished?  What's wrong with the estimation process? What are the patterns?  Are there clues about future velocity?

Answer (score 1):

this is an interesting question. Should the stories automatically move to the next sprint? I would say that unfinished stories become candidates for the next sprint so should go back on the team backlog. If not you might be actually working in a Kanban style with biweekly scrum ceremonies. Which is fine, but good to understand for better context to your question.

Another interesting aspect to your question is that it seems like reporting is driving your decision about what to do with stories rather than progress. This needs deeper exploration as it is very easy to get into a dynamic where reporting to senior leadership becomes the primary concern of the product development team, instead of actual product development :)

I'm not criticising in anyway as I have been in many similar situations, just wanting to explore the context of your question.